# Manually restoring macOS System folder

Tags: time-machine, restore, time-capsule, mojave

I have been trying to restore using migration assistant from an Airport Time Capsule with no success despite following multiple support avenues.

I’m now trying to manually restore all my files but the issue I have encountered is that even using the root account there are certain files that I cannot remove and replace with the files from the backup.

In particular I’m trying to ‘swap out’ the **/Macintosh HD/System/** folder. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Is there a specific reason which prevents you from just reinstalling macOS from Recovery (which updates `/System` but leaves everything else intact)?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you are restoring from backup but you **can't** replace active system files, nor would you want to.

The preferred way to restore a Mac would be to install/reinstall the operating system from whatever source you have. Once that is done use your Time Machine backup to then restore your files, applications and system settings.

The latter would be those files that the system would change to reflect preferences, settings and other changes you have made to macOS. Some of which may be located inside the System folder(s).

Comment: Well it’s useful to know that it’s not possible but restoring from the time machine backup is not working from recovery mode or migration assistant.

Comment: If you can add some detail to your original question and especially information about all of the indications, errors you are getting and procedures you are using to your original question it is likely a mod can open your question back up and help with your issue. But we do need more information to go on.

Comment: Apologies for not closing this out but this has long since been resolved. It turned out that there were a couple corrupt files in the backup preventing a successful restore; once I manually deleted these files I was able to do a full restore. As such this question become irrelevant. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat relevant:

I don't know about System folder, but after a botched update of ruby gems, I used time machine to restore `/Library/Ruby` and that worked fine.